# OLEDB 12.0 is not installed on local machine (ACE Driver)

Tags: sql-server, excel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have this system configuration

Windows Server 2012 - 64 bit (Amazon EC2)

SQL Server 2012 - (Amazon RDS)

On EC2 I am trying to run a utility which will import the data from an excel to SQL Server(RDS) through SSMS.
I was getting an error "OLEDB 12.0 was not registered", I installed ACE driver on EC2. It didn't work. 
 
The Problem which I think is since my SQL server is on different machine i.e RDS. My installed driver cannot add excel importing capabilities to it(I am using openrowset).

I cannot install the ACE driver on RDS since it's just a database.

Can anyone help me in getting a solution to it? Thanks in Advance.

If I do it on a machine which is hosting SQL server and install ACE Driver on it. It works like a charm.

Comment: If I do it on a machine which is hosting SQL server and install ACE Driver on it. It works like a charm.

Comment: install the driver from the following link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920. When the installation is done on a serve make sure to restart the server . To make sure you have the right driver go to SQL server , Linked server , under providers you should be able to see Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was amazon RDS is just a database. So ACE driver service was running on EC2 but not on RDS. In order to work the flow of importing the ace driver should interact with services running on RDS. So I figured out two solutions for it:

1.) Move my database on EC2.
2.) Run this import process on separate machine, Generate Scripts and run through ssms on EC2 to get it stored in RDS.